# State-of-the-art writing in machine learning

Tags: research-process, computer-science, writing

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_the_art), State-of-the-art is as follows

> State-of-the-art (sometimes cutting edge or leading edge) refers to
>   the **highest level of general development**, as of a device, technique,
>   or scientific field achieved at a particular time. However, in some
>   contexts it can also refer to a **level of development reached at any
>   particular time** as a result of the common methodologies employed at
>   the time.

So there are two interpretations for state-of-art: one is general development across time and another one is the  best method available today.

**Which interpretation is apt for state-of-the-art writing in machine learning**?

For example consider a task [Semantic Segmentation on PASCAL VOC 2012 test](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/semantic-segmentation-on-pascal-voc-2012). There are 34 methods to perform that. Among them [DeepLabv3+ (Xception-JFT)](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/encoder-decoder-with-atrous-separable)
has only the SOTA status. Remember that remaining 33 methods might also have SOTA status at their times.

If I need to write and present State-of-the-art on *Semantic Segmentation on PASCAL VOC 2012 test*, then is it enough to present *DeepLabv3+*  and ignore remaining (assume no dependencies) or there is a need to understand remaining also for state-of-the -art?

**Context**: My University generally follows the interpretation I for state-of-the-art, but popular machine learning website [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com) is following interpretation II. So I got confuse and hence asking which one is more apt for state-of-the-art writing. If interpretation II is the actual one,  then there may be possibility for me to convince my guide and act accordingly.

Comment: The field of CS is too broad for a general answer to apply to more than a fraction of it. CS is _not_ just one uniform thing.

Comment: @Buffy narrowed down and seems clear now.

Comment: This seems like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you're asking about the nuances in the definition of "state-of-the-art," but what you really want to know is (I assume) whether your literature review needs to cover every method that has ever been state-of-the-art, or just the one method that is currently state-of-the-art. I suspect if you focus on the second question, you may get better answers.

Comment: @cag51 how the both are different? Actually literature review for us happens long after state-of-the-art. I got this doubt due to the ambiguity in definition of state-of-the-art. Some are following interpretation I and some are following the interpretation II. For me, it's only one for sure. So there is no doubt personally for me(for my academics). I have doubt only with the actual intention and definition of state-of-the-art.

Comment: @cag51 at my college, in general, people follow interpretation I but when I saw website like paperswithcode they are following interpretation II.

Comment: I understand that in your mind, that are two clear options, 1 or 2, and you want us to tell you one or the other. My point is that we will likely see it differently, and that may be why your question attracted close votes. If you can tell us what you're trying to do and why it matters, we may be more useful.

Comment: @cag51 yeah, I edited accordingly... Please let us know if any issues further ..

Comment: If this is about an assignment, then the best person to ask would probably be the one who gave it to you. However, in this context, you're probably expected to talk about the general methods used by the best systems, not about a single specific implementation. - Don't just describe the one highest-scoring system. Look at the top results - what do they have in common? What kind of approaches do they use? (e.g. looking at the names, it seems to mostly involve deep neural networks - what kinds? How are they used? etc...)

Comment: Basically, there's *state-of-the-art system* (e.g. "With their 95% accuracy, the system from Google won the competition.") and *state-of-the-art approach* (e.g. "Nobody uses HMMs for this anymore, it's all neural networks."). It all depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

State of the art refers only to the very highest accuracy ever achieved up to the point that you write your paper in computer science (I work in the field).